# Delete special rows in every sheet via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I tried to write some code to search for a word and if this word isn't found in the first an second column I delete the row.

This code runs through every Sheet.

Unfortunately this script takes like forever and Excel stops working. It works for one sheet but even if there are just 2 rows, it takes like 10 seconds.

Maybe you can help me to work on the performance, because I never learned VBA and this code is the best I was able to write.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dontDeleteRowWithInput()
Dim wksSheet As Worksheet
Dim area As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim rows As Long
Dim Var As String
Dim bool As Boolean
Dim celltxt As String

Var = InputBox("Input", "Input")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Loop over every Worksheet in this Workbook
For Each wksSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set area = wksSheet.UsedRange
    rows = area.Rows.Count
    'Loop the rows backwards until it reaches row 2 (Row 1 should be ignored)
    For j = rows To 2 Step -1
        'Search vor the input in Column 1 and 2
        For i = 1 To 2 Step 1
            'Get the content of the reached cell in string format
            celltxt = Cells(j, i).Value
            'Compare the saved string with the input
            If InStr(celltxt, Var) > 0 Then
                'If the input is found in this cell don't delete the row
                bool = False
                Exit For
            End If
            'Delete the row if the input wasn't found in its columns
            If bool = True Then
                Rows(j).Delete
            End If
            'Reset the bool
            bool = True
        Next i
    Next j
Next wksSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: start substituting `rows = bereich.Rows.Count` with `rows = bereich.UsedRange.Rows.Count` and process only _used_ rows instead of _all_ rows (i.e. some 1 million). BTW: I assume `bereich` is referring to some sheet object

Comment: Could you also add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` to your code (initial and final respectively)? If your workbook has some calculation to do, this will improve the performance of your routine...

Comment: i dont think you need to create variables for everything...you can reference the cell value as cell(i,j).value. you can use it when set once...but when its reassigned regularly in the execution then better to reference it as such instead setting a varaible every time

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. @user3598756 you are right bereich should be `area`.

Comment: `rows = bereich.UsedRange.Rows.Count` doesn't work, since `area = ActiveSheet.UsedRange` already.
@Pspl There are no calculations in this file
@SivaprasathV I removed "celltext" but the performance is still horrible

Comment: If `input` is not found in column A and B then delete row?                            is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something simpler like:

```
Dim wksSheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim Var As String
Var = InputBox("Input", "Input")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Loop over every Worksheet in this Workbook
For Each wksSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wksSheet
        lastrow = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        lastrow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        If lastrow > 0 And Var <> "" Then
            For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
                If InStr(.Cells(i, 1).Text, Var) > 0 Or InStr(.Cells(i, 2).Text, Var) > 0 Then
                    .rows(i).Delete
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I believe this should work for you. It has not been tested yet.

```
Sub dontDeleteRowWithInput()
         Dim sht As Worksheet
         Dim nlast As Long
         For Each sht In Sheets


                nlast = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For n = nlast To 1 Step -1
                    If sht.Cells(n, 1).Value <> "Input" And sht.Cells(n, 2).Value <> "Input" Then
                    sht.Rows(n).EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                    Next n

              Next sht
     End Sub
```

`